# How do I write and IF statement to show certain copy blocks on certain days on the week

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

How can I write an `IF` statement for an email? I am looking to show a certain copy on Monday until Thursday and the other copy information on Friday to Sunday.

Is it possible? If so, how?

Comment: Please add more details about what you are trying to achieve and what have you tried so far?

Comment: Please provide details too if you mean show certain copy dependent on send date or if you mean at time of open, because there is a huge difference

Comment: Hey, I am trying to show content on my email that only shows copy one certains days. From Monday - Thursday one type of copy and Friday until Sunday something else.

Answer (score 4):

See below:

```
%%[SET @DOFW = FormatDate(NOW(), "ddddd")]%%

%%[IF @DOFW == 'Tuesday' THEN]%%
   today is Tuesday
%%[ENDIF]%%
```

This is using the FormatDate function found here:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/FormatDate.htm

The AMPscript Function Reference is a great resource so save it in your bookmarks.

And just to be clear, AMPscript renders at time of send.

Thanks!

Comment: Hey, I added this to my email in the HTML section, but nothing seem to change. Can you help further? Thanks

Comment: Hey @LisaH. Sorry for the delay. What output are you getting from the FormatDate function?